# HttpClient Freeze some user Random

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, owin

I have a method that receive a URL and a filename, the method then make a request to that URL, download the HTML and convert it to a pdf.
The problem is that sometimes the user making the request is completely freezed at client.GetStringAsync(URI_Target), and if that happens, it will always happen, while if it works it will always work (at least for 24h).

One problem is that the target URL require authentication and different users may or not be able to access the target page.

```
//HTTP get method
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string URL, string FileName)
{
  //downloading the html from URl using the same Auth cookies for the current logged user
  string html = await GetHtmlAsync(new Uri(URL), Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Cookies);

  //... convert and return...
}


public static async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(Uri URI_Target, RequestCookieCollection OwinCookieCollection)
    {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            if (OwinCookieCollection != null)
            {
                var rootUrl = new Uri(URI_Target.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
                foreach (var cookie in OwinCookieCollection)
                {
                    cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Key, WebUtility.UrlEncode(cookie.Value)) { Domain = rootUrl.Host });

                }
            }

          //always reach this point, GetStringAsync sometimes takes forever (after a few seconds => System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException)
            var ris = await client.GetStringAsync(URI_Target).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //sometimes reach this point
            return ris;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this not a server side problem?

Comment: It may be, I have a virtual machine with just iis installed (default installation). But I have no idea on why it should act like this. Sometimes it works and it will always work for the rest of the day, sometimes it doesn't and will never work for the rest of the day. and at the same time different user could using it without problems while others freezze

Comment: Are you responsible for the server side as well? If so, can you debug incoming requests while you're seeing those freezes?

Comment: I am debugging it, the debugger stops at the GetStringAsync method, then call it and never returns.

Comment: Debugging the server side. Not the client side.